# Shuffle with a constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, random, shuffle

I have a problem analog to:

We have 20 balls each ball is unique and identified by a number from 1 to 20. The balls numbered from 1 to 5 are yellow, from 6 to 10 green, from 10 to 15 red and from 16 to 20 blue. Find a method to randomly shuffle the balls while respecting the constraint: "2 successive balls cannot have the same color".

Example:

[image: input/output example]

I have considered two methods that I am not satisfied with, and I am looking for a better one

1. draw a ball at random, then draw a ball at random among all the others having a different color from the previous one, etc.

Problem: we can fall in cases where it is impossible to finish the drawing, if there are only remaining balls of the same color for example.

2. divide the balls into 4 sets of 5 balls (1 per color), form 5 other sets of 4 balls by randomly drawing a ball of each color. Reassemble these 5 sets in order to respect the criterion (the first balls of the last set are permuted until the criterion is respected).

Problem some combinations are never drawn, for example red, yellow, red, yellow ... green, blue, green, blue.

**Edit:**

Here is an implementation of Unlikus solution. Many thanks to him.

```
import enum
import random

Color = enum.Enum('Color', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE', "YELLOW"])

NB_PERMUTATION = {
        (Color.RED, 1, 0, 0, 0): 1,
        (Color.GREEN, 0, 1, 0, 0): 1,
        (Color.BLUE, 0, 0, 1, 0): 1,
        (Color.YELLOW, 0, 0, 0, 1): 1,
        (Color.RED, 0, 0, 0, 0): 0,
        (Color.GREEN, 0, 0, 0, 0): 0,
        (Color.BLUE, 0, 0, 0, 0): 0,
        (Color.YELLOW, 0, 0, 0, 0): 0,
    }

def compute_nb_permutations(*args):
    try:
        return NB_PERMUTATION[args]
    except KeyError:
        second_colors = {1, 2, 3, 4} - {args[0].value}
        nb_ball = [args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]]
        nb_ball[args[0].value - 1] -= 1
        result = NB_PERMUTATION[args] = sum(
            compute_nb_permutations(Color(c), *nb_ball) for c in second_colors if nb_ball[c - 1] > 0
        )
        return result

def arrange_color():
    colors = {*Color}
    nb_ball = [5,5,5,5]

    # choose uniformly among colors for the first ball
    results = [random.choices(list(colors))[0]]
    nb_ball[results[-1].value - 1] -= 1

    while nb_ball != [0,0,0,0]:
        candidates = list(colors - {results[-1]})
        weights = [compute_nb_permutations(c, *nb_ball) for c in candidates]
        results.append(random.choices(candidates, weights=weights)[0])
        nb_ball[results[-1].value - 1] -= 1

    return results

def draw():
    numbers = {
        Color.RED: list(range(1,6)),
        Color.GREEN: list(range(6, 11)),
        Color.BLUE: list(range(11, 16)),
        Color.YELLOW: list(range(16, 21)),
    }
    for v in numbers.values():
        random.shuffle(v)

    return {numbers[c].pop(): c.name for c in arrange_color()}
```

Comment: Do you only need it for the 5+5+5+5 configuration, or does it have to work more generally?

Comment: Only for the 5+5+5+5 configuration would be a good start :)

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, please add a tag for the programming language you want to use

Comment: Matt Timmermans proposition will always give you valid positions to insert, but your implementation is not correct, see @Dave comment on the answer.
But the proposition will not sample uniformly from all valid combinations.
Use Davids approach if you don't need speed because easy to implement, use my approach if performance is relevant to you. Both sample uniformly.

Comment: Solutions belong into **answers**, not into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to calculate the number of permutations which obey your constrains.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208392/ways-to-arrange-4-different-colour-balls-with-no-two-of-the-same-colour-next-to for an answer how to calculate the number of ways to arrange your balls with the first one being one particular color. (The answer deals with the last one, but the numbers are the same). You can calculate the values of f by dynamic programming.

Now you sample your first color in proportion to f(5,5,5,5,red), f(5,5,5,5,green), f(5,5,5,5,blue), f(5,5,5,5, yellow).

Suppose you have sampled red (the first color in f).
You sample the second color in proportion to f(4,5,5,5,green), f(4,5,5,5,blue), f(4,5,5,5, yellow) and so on. You are guarantied that the sum of these 3 values is greater than 0, so there are still solutions left, otherwise f(5,5,5,5, red) would already be 0.

If you have the colors right, the numbers are then easy.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's helpful, but I have to admit I am a little bit lost with the math here ^^'

Comment: Also, my problem is slightly more complicated as I'm not interested in the color of the balls but by the numbers of the ball in the arrangements. So for n = 0 and m = 2 they are 4 possible arrangement (not 2).

Comment: @RenépaulDebroize yes, but if you have an assignment of colors, its trivial to shuffle the numbers of the balls into the respective colors.

Comment: @Unikus indeed, therefore the last statement of your post I guess ^^'

Comment: Thanks again, someone was able to help me with the math. It's funny to see that someone else came up with a very similar formulation of the problem. In my case, it doesn't really have anything to do with balls and colors.

Answer (score 5):

At this scale you could do rejection sampling. On average, it takes less than a hundred tries to find a valid order.

```py
import itertools
import random


deck = range(1, 21)


def color(i):
    return "RGBY"[(i - 1) // 5]


shuffle_count = 0


def sample():
    global shuffle_count
    order = list(deck)
    while True:
        shuffle_count += 1
        random.shuffle(order)
        if all(color(i) != color(j) for (i, j) in itertools.pairwise(order)):
            return order


n = 1000
for j in range(n):
    sample()
print(shuffle_count / n)
print(sample())
```

Sample output:

```
87.227
[3, 10, 15, 4, 18, 5, 11, 17, 7, 19, 8, 2, 14, 20, 1, 12, 9, 13, 16, 6]
```

Comment: It's reasonable indeed

Comment: rejection sampling like this would ensure that all valid results are selected uniformly which is a nice property.  though I'd be tempted to use `itertools.pairwise` to turn the comparison into `all(color(i) != color(j) for i, j in itertools.pairwise(order))`

Comment: @SamMason oh, neat, let me change that.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to repeatedly select 4 balls of different colors, then in random order, select one of the valid positions for each ball in the output list, putting the ball in the selected position.

You can make this very efficient if you're clever about keeping track of valid positions for each color, but that's not necessary if you only have 20 balls. Each time you have to select a position for a particular color, just scan all the output list so far and make a list of the valid ones.

This procedure is guaranteed to never get stuck, because if you've inserted *4n* balls and you have to then insert a blue one, for example, then there are 4n+1 possible positions, but at most 2n of those are adjacent to a blue ball.

Comment: I was misreading this at first. In case anyone else has the same misreading, MT means for us to place the balls adjacent to each other in each step (like inserting into a linked list), not placing them in legal positions in an array.

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: This does not work. For 3 colors and 6 balls, it will not sample all possible permutations with equal probability. I have some code to proof it, but don't know where to share it.
For example: (3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3): 0.0277 and (2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3): 0.037

Comment: @Unlikus There was no stated requirement for uniform probability.  If that is required, then your answer or David's answer are to be preferred.

Comment: I guess this is implied, because otherwise you could just output always one sequence

Comment: That's a little disingenuous.

Comment: This was an extreme example to make the point. A sampling algorithm does not make sense if you don't specify the distribution. And the distribution of your algorithm could be anything. Some sequences are twice as likely as others in the example I showed

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

The essence is this: separate the list of balls into four sublists by color. Since we'll be popping from each sublist, we shuffle each of them before passing them to our primary function `random_sort` so that all popping is essentially random.

For each slot in our final list, function `random_sort` randomly chooses a color to pick from such that no two successive balls have the same color. As you correctly pointed out, the tricky part is not accidentally picking colors in such a way that you have only one color left but more than one slot. This is what function `correct_proportions` handles.

```
class Ball:
     def __init__ (self, color, number):
     self.color = color
     self.number = number            


def random_sort(grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4):
    final = []
    balls_grouped_by_color = [grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4];
    last_list_index = -1
    current = -1
    count = 0
    
    while count < 20:             
        while(True):
            while current == last_list_index or len(balls_grouped_by_color[current]) == 0:
                current = random.randint(0, 3)        
                       
            correction = correct_proportions(balls_grouped_by_color)
            if correction != -1 and correction != last_list_index:
                current = correction            
            break
        
        final.append(balls_grouped_by_color[current].pop())    
        last_list_index = current                    
        count += 1                      
    return final    


def correct_proportions(colors):
    index_of_disproportionate = -1

    for i in range(len(colors)):
        sum_others = sum(len(l) for l in colors) - len(colors[i])
        if len(colors[i]) >= sum_others:
            index_of_disproportionate = i;
            break            
    return index_of_disproportionate    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    yellow_balls = [Ball('Y', 1), Ball('Y', 2), Ball('Y', 3), Ball('Y', 4), Ball('y', 5)]
    green_balls  = [Ball('G', 6), Ball('G', 7), Ball('G', 8), Ball('G', 9), Ball('G', 10)]
    red_balls  = [Ball('R', 11), Ball('R', 12), Ball('R', 13), Ball('R', 14), Ball('R', 15)]
    blue_balls  = [Ball('B', 16), Ball('B', 17), Ball('B', 18), Ball('B', 19), Ball('B', 20)]

    shuffle(yellow_balls);
    shuffle(green_balls);
    shuffle(red_balls);
    shuffle(blue_balls);

    final_order = random_sort(yellow_balls, green_balls, red_balls, blue_balls)   
 
    for ball in final_order:
        print(ball.color + '-' + str(ball.number))
```

I'm not crazy about having three nested loops, but this gets the job done.

Note also I am not a Python programmer, so I may not have used the most modern or elegant conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the randomness of a trial & error approach by starting from a valid arrangement and making a number of valid swaps:

```
import random

def shuffleBalls(A):
    A.sort(key=lambda n:(n%5,n))
    for _ in A:
        bx  = [b for p,b,n in zip([0]+A,A,A[1:]+[0]) if (p-1)//5 != (n-1)//5]
        b   = random.choice(bx)
        A.remove(b)
        ix = [ i for i,(p,n) in enumerate(zip([0]+A,A)) 
               if (b-1)//5 not in [(p-1)//5,(n-1)//5]]
        A.insert(random.choice(ix),b)
```

- Sorting the list by modulo 5 ensures that no ball of the same color are contiguous:
- `[5, 10, 15, 20, 1, 6, 11, 16, 2, 7, 12, 17, 3, 8, 13, 18, 4, 9, 14, 19]`
- `for _ in A:` will make as many swaps as there are items in the list
- Each swap is performed in two steps: 1) remove a random item, 2) insert it back at a random position
- `bx` is the list of items that can be removed without leaving balls of the same color next to each other
- A random item of `bx` is selected and removed from `A`
- `ix` is the list of index positions that are eligible for insertion of `b`.  The item at these indexes and the previous ones are not the same color as `b`
- Pick a random index from `ix` and insert `b` there
- There will always be at least 11 eligible positions in `ix` given that, after removing `b`, the remaining 4 balls with the same color as `b` remaining in `A` can invalidate at most 2 positions each (out of 19).

output:

```
A = list(range(1,21))

shuffleBalls(A)
[3, 10, 4, 20, 15, 5, 6, 13, 16, 2, 17, 7, 12, 18, 9, 14, 8, 1, 11, 19]

shuffleBalls(A)
[20, 15, 3, 17, 8, 5, 6, 4, 16, 11, 19, 7, 12, 18, 10, 2, 13, 9, 14, 1]
```